# Converting nHibernate sql to manual sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nhibernate

I'm tracking down an nHibernate problem. `Exception thrown: 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' in NHibernate.dll` is all it is telling me. I have `show_sql` set to true. So I thought I would try the sql from nHibernate manually in in SQL Server Management Studio. I added the DECLARE statements. Now I get this error: `Incorrect syntax near '@p0'' when executing on the last line. What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @p0 VARCHAR(50);  
DECLARE @p1 INT;  
DECLARE @p2 DATETIME;  
DECLARE @p3 INT;  
DECLARE @p4 VARCHAR(10);  
DECLARE @p5 VARCHAR(50);  
DECLARE @p6 VARCHAR(80);  
DECLARE @p7 DECIMAL(11,2);  
DECLARE @p8 DATETIME;  
DECLARE @p9 VARCHAR(80);  
DECLARE @p10 INT;  
DECLARE @p11 VARCHAR(50);  

INSERT INTO MMDAML.dbo.tblMyProjectTable   
(Name, Size, UploadDate, RefId, RefType, Type, Alias, Amount, Date, Number, Stage, Caption) VALUES   
(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11);   
select SCOPE_IDENTITY();  
@p0 = 'Project317.png' [Type: String (4000)], @p1 = 77756 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p2 = 4/14/2017 10:51:54 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], @p3 = 317 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p4 = 'Project' [Type: String (4000)], @p5 = 'Invoice' [Type: String (4000)], @p6 = 'Contract.png' [Type: String (4000)], @p7 = 4455 [Type: Decimal (0)], @p8 = 4/14/2017 10:51:23 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], @p9 = '987987' [Type: String (4000)], @p10 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p11 = NULL [Type: String (4000)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`;` is a symbol for separating the batch, you have to add `SET` or another `SELECT` keyword before `@p0` to make it a complete statement. For example,

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY();  
SET @p0 = 'Project317.png'...
```

OR

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY();  
SELECT @p0 = 'Project317.png'...
```

Comment: That gets me most of the way there. I also had to remove the [Type: *] and put the date parameter values in quotes and also move the SET to before the INSERT.